# Отображение количества товаров на рисунке корзины

Tags: php, html, css, cookie, сессия

Как сделать так, что если пользователь не вышел в прошлом разе из аккаунта на сайте, то при следующей загрузке будет отображаться количество товаров на корзине (в красном кружке в правом верхнем углу в квадрате с рисунком корзины) (хотелось бы по пунктам и подробно)?

Comment: речь идет о каком то движке? или вы пишете сайт сами, с нуля?

Comment: сам , с нуля (не на движке)

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из того, что вы не указали тэг "database/mysql/etc" ответ будет следующим:

Я предлагаю хранить элементы корзины покупок в сеансе пользователя ( $_SESSION ). Если они нужны для сохранения между сеансами, дополнительно поместите их в таблицу базы данных.

В переменных сеанса они защищены от взлома (они на стороне сервера), и вам не нужно беспокоиться о раскрытии информации (все, что находится в файле cookie или $_GET параметре, это идентификатор сеанса).

Допустим user_id, item_id, и quantity. При этом user_id логично будет прописать в куках чтобы определять пользователя. Только не храните user_id в куках в прямом виде, обязательно в шифровоном хоть как-то, хотябы md5() чтобы избежать перебора злоумышленниками.

Удачи...